Git Extensions showing my own repo under submodules
I created a repo using Git Extensions (v4.2).  The submodules pane shows my own repo under Submodules icon, although I do not have any submodules in my repo. The image attached shows this behavior. I do not have any idea why does my repo appears under Submodules. Is it a bug?
Submodules Git Extensions
I expect that my repo should not appear under Submodules rather only the submodules that will be added to the repo.
